# Настройка multiprocessing python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.6, multiprocessing

У меня есть долго работающий код, который я хочу ускорить за счет параллельного выполнения. По шагам:

1. Загрузка архива с сервера по API
2. Распаковка и извлечение необходимых файлов.
3. Конвертация и обработка файлов.
4. Публикация.

Так как без результата выполнения предыдущего процесса не может работать следующий, пришлось играться с `time.sleep`, но это под конкретный случай, так как количество архивов может быть разное.
Помогите, пожалуйста, избавиться от `time.sleep`, чтобы он не прекращал процесс, пока не выполнится полностью предыдущий.

Код:

```
import sys
import glob, os
import datetime
import time
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pool

start_time = time.time()

startDate = sys.argv[1]
finishDate = sys.argv[2]

os.system('python3 /var/www/html/algorithm/tiles/delete_all.py')

def step1():
    os.system('python3 /var/www/html/algorithm/tiles/download_all.py '+startDate+' '+finishDate)

def step2():
    time.sleep(300)
    os.system('python3 /var/www/html/algorithm/tiles/walk.py ')


def step3():
    time.sleep(500)
    os.system('python3 /var/www/html/algorithm/sentinel_gpgeo/public/walk.py ')


def step4():
    time.sleep(900)
    os.system('python3 /var/www/html/algorithm/sentinel_gpgeo/public/public.py ')
    
def main():
    p1 = Process(target=step1)
    p1.start()

    p2 = Process(target=step2)
    p2.start()

    p3 = Process(target=step3)
    p3.start()

    p4 = Process(target=step4)
    p4.start()


    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

    

print("Number of cpu : ", multiprocessing.cpu_count())

os.system('python3 /var/www/html/algorithm/tiles/delete_all.py ')

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Зачем мультипроцессинг, если в итоге нужно чтобы задачи последовательно выполнялись?

Comment: @insolor потому что хочу ускорить выполнение кода. При полностью последовательном выполнении пока не завершится полностью один шаг, система не приступит к выполнению следующего. Уже на таких кривых time.sleep-ах я ускоряю код на 10%.

Comment: Не знаю, что у вас там ускоряется, но если задачи выполняются последовательно, хоть в одном процессе, хоть в несколько - они выполняются последовательно (время выполнения равно сумме времени выполнения каждой из задач), значит никакого прироста производительности не будет. Если прирост есть, значит задачи пересекаются по времени, следовательно они выполняются не последовательно, и если одна задача зависит от другой, то результат будет неправильным.

Comment: @insolor смотрите: Шаг первый. Скачать архивы по списку. Их может быть опубликовано от 1 до 10. Возьмем, к примеру, 5. Пока не скачаются все 5, программа не приступит ко второму шагу - распаковке.  И так далее.

Comment: @insolor с мультипроцессингом при скачивании уже первого из пяти архивов программа приступает к распаковке, параллельно докачиваются следующие архивы. И так далее. Вот за счет этого и идет ускорение

Comment: @Константин так в чем суть вашего вопроса? С одной стороны хотите `чтобы он не прекращал процесс, пока не выполнится полностью предыдущий`, а с другой `хочу ускорить за счет параллельного выполнения`.

Comment: Чтобы добиться нужного Вам функционала, необходимо будет, как самый простой вариант, вставить код из запускаемых скриптов непосредственно в этот же проект и использовать средства синхронизации потоков. В противном случае добро пожаловать в межпроцессное взаимодействие.

Comment: Тогда: 1 - нужно вызывать каждую задачу не через os.system, а как функцию, 2 -  каждая задача должна знать, что она работает через мультипроцессинг, 3 - предыдущая задача должна держать семафор/лок, и отпускать его, когда готова передать данные следующей задаче, а следующая задача должна ждать отпускания семафора/лока, только после этого начинать выполнение. p.s. собственно, то что V-Mor выше написал

Comment: @RomanKonoval в том, как избавится от костылей в виде time.sleep. Потому что без них начинается скачивание. Все три следующих шага пробуют запуститься и найти файлы, с которыми им нужно работать. Не находят. Завершаются. Результат: архивы скачались, а остальные процессы уже завершились, так как  они не увидели, с чем им работать

Comment: @V-Mor ,благодарю. Пошел ковырять взаимодействие. Просто я в разработке новичок, вот и мучаю людей)

Comment: @insolor , благодарю. Пошел ковырять взаимодействие. Просто я в разработке новичок, вот и мучаю людей)

Comment: @V-Mor мучаю межпроцессорное взаимодействие. Но все примеры заточены на передачу результата работы процесса в качестве аргумента дальше. У меня результат же - файл. Подскажете,  в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Передавайте имя файла